# html table how to make three tr on the same line

Tags: html, css

this is a jsfiddle to my code

https://jsfiddle.net/sb73g9kr/1/

my problem is that there will absoultey scroll since i have many `tr` to add, but if i make three tr at the same line, i won't have a problem

could you help me please to make three tr on the same line?

when my code was this:

```
#agentsTable tr {
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

it was each tr on a specific line, but then i tried to do this:

```
#agentsTable tr {
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and as you see in the jsfiddle, there are many empty spaces between the cells.

what i would like to do is having three tr on the same line, but the should have the same width, without any space

Comment: Why not to use td and nested table ?

Comment: Why use tables at all if you're relying on floats? Does this need to be responsive?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after here could be done as the above example explains(using td's as they should be used) . Not sure why you're using a table if you're going to use css to make it act like something else.

If you want to keep the tables, choose the above answer, otherwise change the markup and change the css to use block elements and floats to achieve this behavior.

css rule to achieve this behavior:

```
.agentLabel, .talkingAgentClass{
box-sizing:border-box;
width:29%;
margin:0 2% 10px;
float:left;
height:90px;
text-align:center;
min-width:100px;
}
```

[See this fiddle for example.](https://jsfiddle.net/sb73g9kr/10/)

Also note the use of the helper span in the divs, this is to keep text vertically aligned in the divs.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML to fix this.

Put three `<td>`s in each `<tr>`.

Table rows (tr) comprise of a group of table cells (td - stands for table datum) - you can have as many td's inside a tr as you need.

[Like this jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sb73g9kr/4/)

```
<tr >
    <td class="talkingAgentClass">somthing</td>
    <td class="talkingAgentClass">somthing</td>    
    <td class="talkingAgentClass">somthing</td>
</tr>
```

Note, to acheive the effect I also altered the css, removing the `display: inline-block;` and applying `width: 33%;` to the `<td>`

Finally, to make the agents header span three columns, use `colspan='3'` on the td, as you [can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/sb73g9kr/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#agentsTable td {
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sb73g9kr/7/

Answer (score -1):

Your question itself wrong in html a line means a row represented as tr thn how can u use tr thrice in a same row.